# How to show image label when paste it in Wygwam field?

Tags: wygwam

I need to show label (img alt or title property text) under the image when paste this image in Wygwam. Does exists the way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'under'? If you mean visually display the alt text, it is a WYSIWYG field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean on the frontend of the website, rather than in the Wygwam field.

There's a few different approaches, personally the easiest and most straight forward for both the developer and CMS editors, would be to implement on the frontend via JavaScript ([example](http://davemcmillan.net/use-jquery-to-display-an-image-alt-tag-as-a-caption-overlay/)), so parses the text area taking title and adding beneath as a p or label tag. Therefore no different for CMS editor to add images and nothing special needs to be done each time.

Alternatives would be...

Utilise an [existing JQuery library](http://captionjs.com/)

Adding custom parsing in PHP or in a plugin within the template (a lot more effort)

Or utilising [Wygwam templates](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/wygwam-creating-a-custom-template) - may be more complex for editors to add images each time and for you to build initially

Google "ckeditor", as Wygwam is based on it, a lot of its functionality and features can be utilised.

Comment: Peter, thank you!
I was surprised that I can't add image caption just by using standart wygwam function "add image". So wygwam templates way is more usefull for me.